# How to extract specific nodes from an xml file with their parents?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml file from which I want to extract nodes whose id attribute is "Needed":

```
<root>
<level1 id="NotNeeded">
</level1>
<level1 id="Needed">
    <level2 id="Needed">
        <level3 id="Needed">I need this one</level3>
        <level3 id="NotNeeded1">I don't need this one</level3>
    </level2>
    <level2 id="notNeeded">
        <level3 id="notNeeded">I don't need this one</level3>
    </level2>
</level1>
</root>
```

(Depth is arbitrary)
I need to transform it into the following form:

```
<root>
<level1 id="Needed">
    <level2 id="Needed">
        <level3 id="Needed">I need this one</level3>
    </level2>
</level1>
</root>
```

What I'm trying to do (with pseudocode, I hope it's clear):

```
myextraction=[element with id "Needed"]
while [myextraction has parent]
{
 myextraction=myextraction.[parent without children].Addtochildren(myextraction)
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this? (A built-in method maybe?)

Comment: Your problem statement leaves out one case: what if the parent is `NotNeeded` but a child element is?

Comment: I used NotNeeded for nodes only that don't have a Needed child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Linq` to `Xml` and do this.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
doc.Descendants()  
   .Where(x=>x.Attribute("id") != null && x.Attribute("id").Value == "NotNeeded")
   .Remove();
```

**Ouput :**

```
 <root>
  <level1 id="Needed">
    <level2 id="Needed">
      <level3 id="Needed">I need this one</level3>
    </level2>
  </level1>
</root>
```

Check this [`fiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2pcTT9)

Comment: Small tip, the query can make use of the explicit conversions to reduce to `.Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "NotNeeded")`.